# Javascript code that listens to DOM events in a page

Tags: javascript

Ideally, I want to have a javascript file which needs to be injected to my web page to track user activities (similar to ga.js by Google Analytics).

The aim of code in the js file is to capture any DOM events and find out what action was done by the user in the page.

Is there any kind of event emmiters available in client side ? I have heard of node.js event emmitter module in server side.

Looking for a similar kind of functionality which I need to achieve in the client side.

Actually, in order to use Event handlers we must already know what all controls are there in the web page and what all events can be raised in the page.

In my case the web page is dynamic so I can't attach event handlers directly.                                                                                                                             For eg, Suppose these are the controls in the page , a button and a text box.

```
<button id="myBtn"> Click me </button> 
<input id="myTxt" type="text"> Enter text </input>
```

I am looking for a functionality as the javascript code below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}

</script>
```

Clearly, the above piece of code can handle only click events in the page. What I am looking for is a more generic approach which makes it possible to handle any event that occurs in the DOM.

Comment: node.js has a modue called mutation_summary js and mutation_observer js which I feel you could make use of it in your code if you are using node.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a solution. Just implemented the monitorEvents method which is available in the Google Chrome console.

Please find below the jsfiddle link :

https://jsfiddle.net/1v8vmr06/6/

```
function monitorEvents(element) {
  var log = function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
            };
  var events = [];

  for(var i in element) {
    //console.log(i);
    if(i.startsWith("on")) events.push(i.substr(2));
  }

  events.forEach(function(eventName) { 
    //console.log(eventName);
    if(eventName == "click" || eventName == "keyup"){
      element.addEventListener(eventName, log); 
    }
  }); 
}

monitorEvents(document.body);
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly this should be the basic JavaScript events:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Check those out and see if it helps.

Comment: Actually, this is possible if we already know what all controls are there in the web page. In my case the web page is dynamic so I can't attach event handlers directly.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need to set eventListeners for every type of event you need, attach them to document and operate with events target field.